# Camel aggregation of XMLs based on the value of XML elements

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I have the following XMLs:

**XML1:**

```
<Person>

<Name>Ben</Name>

<Adress>1234</Address>

</Person>
```

**XML2:**

```
<Person>

<Name>Johnson</Name>

<Adress>5678</Address>

</Person>
```

**XML3:**

```
<Person>

<Name>Harry</Name>

<Adress>1234</Address>

</Person>
```

I want to aggregate the XMLs only if the attribute value of the **Address** element is the same, so in this case XML1 and XML3 will be aggregated to look like:

```
<Person>

<Name>Ben</Name>

<Adress>1234</Address>

</Person>

<Person>

<Name>Harry</Name>

<Adress>1234</Address>

</Person>
```

(P.S: Result need not be an XML, can be a string).
Is it possible using Camel ?

```
from ("direct:x")
..............
.to(output)
```

Comment: But what if Address 5678 repeats? Do you need to aggregate Addresses with more than one occurrence?

Comment: Yes, if 5678 repeats, that would have to be aggregated as well

Comment: You can use an xpath expression to correlate on the /Person/Address value

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I will take, In fact I have done it already.

1. Use a simple processor to aggregate all these XML's to a single XML
2. Write a XSLT to create your desired XML from the aggregated XML, that way if at all you want to change your logic, you can just do it inside XSLT. XSLT is powerful this way.

I would hesitate to either keep these kind of logic in camel routes or write a pojo to do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to make use of Camel's approach if there was a way handling it during the exchange

Comment: I get it, But you might want to handle multiple scenarios. What is the maximum number of XML's you expect ? And how many address matches you will have to make ? Like this 1234 is going to a static value ? Or do you get this value from some other service  ? If you get this from a service, I get your idea. It makes sense to do it in Camel. You can have a simple route , to filter only these address XML's . But if you want to do it for multiple addresses, yes technically possible in camel but a mapping table in Camel would look ugly ;)